# Getting error while connecting mongo db, how to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.     at _createMongoClient

not able to connect mongodb
Some code

[image: 1]

my env file

[image: 2]

connecting the mongo db

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: can you also paste the error logs in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

1. You have to access the env variable using `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE_NAME`?
2. For accessing the env variable, you have to load the env variables from .env file into `process.env` using some library like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)
3. You have to give a name to the env variable making it a key value pair after which it will be loaded into `process.env` under the name of the variable. eg.

.env file

```
MONGODB_URI=mongo+srv://Aditya........
```

4. You have not properly written the password in the connection string. The password can not be `******`. You have to remove the asterisks and replace them with the password you generated manually or had MongoDB generate automatically while creating the database. If you don't have the password which can only be seen once, go to database user settings, add another user or edit the current user to update the password and then copy it once and store it somewhere

Comment: i typed **** for security reasons